React Native iOS App - Uploading m4a file to AWS S3
Building a react ios app that uses the following library to record audio: https://github.com/hyochan/react-native-audio-recorder-player
I am able to successfully record the audio and play it back. I can see the file in my cache/local-system.
I want to upload this file to s3. I am able to upload a text file with static text (via Body: parameter) but can't figure out how to get this file uploaded:
file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FA7E2611-EB5F-492E-A0AD-22691F4DCF84/data/Containers/Data/Application/4A95C0DC-6565-4531-87E9-EC42C7A62127/Library/Caches/hello.m4a
things i've tried:
const data = '';
    const readFile = async (path) => {
      const response = await RNFS.readFile(path);
      data = response;
    };

const fileStream = RNFS.readFile(this.fileUrl);

  const parallelUploads3 = new Upload({
    client: new S3({}) || new S3Client({}),
    params: { Bucket: S3_BUCKET, Key: 'hello.m4a', Body: fileStream },
    queueSize: 4,
    partSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
    leavePartsOnError: false,
  });

I'm used to Java where I can just create something like
new File(pathToURL);
Any help would be appreciated.
See above for the code examples
The latest error i'm getting with the above code is:
Error uploading file: [Error: Body Data is unsupported format, expected data to be one of: string | Uint8Array | Buffer | Readable | ReadableStream | Blob;.]
